# How come my function does not run in my AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want a function to run when my iOS application first launches, so I placed it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

within AppDelegate.m. However, my function is not getting called when my app starts up. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your AppDelegate isn't being created and/or added as the delegate of the application. Are you doing this with a XIB or programmatically?

Check if your -init and/or -awakeFromNib routines are being invoked.

Comment: I'm doing this programmatically by copying and pasting  `[self.mainViewController loadArrayOfAnimalsFromPlist];` into my AppDelegate.

Comment: Check to be sure self.mainViewController isn't nil.

Comment: the line in your comment won't create your delegate. you are sure your delegate is being created? What class name are you passing to `UIApplicationMain()`?